# classic binding works but compiletime binding acts only onetime

Tags: xaml, mvvm, uwp, mvvm-light, uwp-xaml

I have a mistake in my code, but I cannot see it. So I have a FlipView which has multiple DataTemplates. Now I want the view to be updated on a PropertyChange in the vm - so I use databinding.

But if I use compile time Binding, the binding only behave as it would be set to OneTime - even if the mode is set to OneWay or TwoWay. So I thought they may be something wrong with the OnPropertyChanged event- but I could not find anything. Therefore I tried to switch to classic binding - **and it works**. So my question is what I am doing wrong with x:Bind?

Here a simplified version of the XAML:

```
<Page
   [...]
    DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=GalleryViewModelInstance}">

    <Page.Resources>
        [...]

        <DataTemplate x:Name="FlipImageTemplate"  x:DataType="gallery:IMediaAttachmentViewModel">
            <Image Stretch="UniformToFill"HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
                <Image.Source>
                    <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding AttachmentViewModel.RelativeAttachmentPath, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource UriConverter}}" />
                </Image.Source>
            </Image>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Name="FlipVideoAudioTemplate" x:DataType="gallery:IMediaAttachmentViewModel">
            [...]
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Name="FlipPDFTemplate"  x:DataType="gallery:IMediaAttachmentViewModel" >
            [...]
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Name="FlipOtherTemplate" >
            [...]
        </DataTemplate>

        <local:BigPictureDataTemplateSelector x:Key="BigPictureDataTemplateSelector" 
                                              ImageTemplate="{StaticResource FlipImageTemplate}"
                                              VideoAndAudioTemplate="{StaticResource FlipVideoAudioTemplate}"
                                              PdfTemplate="{StaticResource FlipPDFTemplate}"
                                              OtherTemplate="{StaticResource FlipOtherTemplate}"/>
    </Page.Resources>

    <RelativePanel x:Name="relativePanel" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                   Padding="40,40,40,40">

            <FlipView x:Name="FlipView"  
                SelectedIndex="{x:Bind ViewModel.FilpViewIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"
                ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.GalleryDataViewModels, Mode=TwoWay}"
                ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource BigPictureDataTemplateSelector}">
            </FlipView>
       [...]
    </RelativePanel>
</Page>
```

So if I change the binding to x:bind it is not updating the view (as the Mode would be set to OneTime)

```
 <BitmapImage UriSource="{x:Bind AttachmentViewModel.RelativeAttachmentPath, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource UriConverter}}" />
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug the generated compile time bindings?

Comment: What about rest of the code? Do you change object instance of the ViewModel, or any binded properties?